# Critiquing my first python script, looking for advise

Tags: python-3.5

Looking for all of the errors in my code, I'm positive there are quite a few, I was wondering if someone  could point them out and possibly quickly explain how I could fix them..

```
import time
import re

cls=("\n" * 50)

fname=input("Please enter your first name:: ")
lname=input("Please enter your last name:: ")

while True:
    age= str (input("Please enter your age:: "))
    if re.search('[0-9]', age):
        break

while True:

    print("Welcome to python ",fname," ",lname,", your current age is ",age, sep="", end="")
    print(", This string should not break")

    addageyorn=input("Would you like to add X amount of years to your age, y or n:: ")

    if addageyorn==("y"):
        addage=input("How many years do you want to add to your age:: ")
        print("OK, so you want to add ",addage," years to your current age of ",age, sep="", end="")
        exeaddage = int(age) + int(addage)
        computed = str(exeaddage)
        print(", In ",addage," years you will be ",computed," years old, thanks for signing in.", sep="")
        time.sleep(5)
        exit()

    if addageyorn==("n"):
        print("Thanks for signing in")
        time.sleep(5)
        exit()

    elif addageyorn!=("y", "n"):
        print("Invalid Input")
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not much sure about this,you need `+` operator to concatinate variables

```
import time
import re

cls=("\n" * 50)

fname=input("Please enter your first name:: ")
lname=input("Please enter your last name:: ")

while True:
    age= str (input("Please enter your age:: "))
    if re.search('[0-9]', age):
        break

while True:

    print("Welcome to python "+fname," "+lname+", your current age is "+age)
    print(", This string should not break")

    addageyorn=input("Would you like to add X amount of years to your age, y or n:: ")

    if addageyorn==("y"):
        addage=input("How many years do you want to add to your age:: ")
        print("OK, so you want to add "+addage+" years to your current age of "+age)
        exeaddage = int(age) + int(addage)
        computed = str(exeaddage)
        print(", In "+addage+" years you will be ",computed," years old, thanks for signing in.")
        time.sleep(5)
        exit()

    if addageyorn==("n"):
        print("Thanks for signing in")
        time.sleep(5)
        exit()

    elif addageyorn!=("y", "n"):
        print("Invalid Input")
```